# Отправка формы по адресу, выбранному внутри тега <select>

Tags: php, javascript, form

Есть форма

```
<form action="/post/сюда_подставить_значение_where/post.php" method="post">
// какие-то поля
<select name="where">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">отправить</button>
```

Надо до отправки формы подставить значение из `select` в адрес в параметре `action` данной формы.
Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, вам нужно передать параметр в ссылку?

Comment: @Zicrael да мне нужно передать выбранное value из данного select'а в параметр action данной формы

Comment: Думаю хорошим и верным вариантом будет написать функцию при сабмите формы которая будет брать `value`  из `select`.

Comment: @Zicrael если вы имеете в виду, что принимать запрос, обрабатывать его, и перенаправлять по нужному адресу, то, к сожалению, не подойдёт(( нужно подставить значение именно до отправки формы

Comment: Готово :) Проверяйте

Answer (score 1):

Думаю хорошим и верным вариантом будет написать функцию при сабмите формы которая будет брать `value` из `select`

```js
    function sendData() {
        const selectedVal = document.getElementsByClassName('where')[0].value;
        const link = `/post/${selectedVal}/post.php`;
        alert(`send data to '${link}'`);
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("post", `${link}`, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="sendData()">
      Enter name: <input type="text">
       <select class="where">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: я бы еще поменял `getElementsByClassName` на `querySelector` что бы не стучать на `[0]` нод листа

Answer (score 1):

**Можно попробовать так: (JQuery)**

```js
//1) Отлавливаем событие отправки формы
//2) Выбираем селект
//3) Выбираем родительскую форму нашего select
//4) Вставляем action
//5) Вывод на экран action алертом
//6) return false, чтобы форма не отправлялась, в боевой версии убрать

$("form").submit(function() {
  var select = $("select[name='where']");
  var parentForm = $(select).parent();
  $(parentForm).attr("action", "/post/"+ select.val() +"/post.php");

  alert("Твой action: " + parentForm.attr("action") );

  return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="/post/сюда_подставить_значение_where/post.php" method="post">
  // какие-то поля
  <select name="where">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">отправить</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```